# if condition gas price in solidity

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix

I have a question do these if conditions take same gas  mean if condition body with && or || with simple if condition with true or false? Same gas  or different? How can I check that?

```
if(msg.sender != MainFounderAddress && msg.sender != teamAddress && msg.sender != adviserAddress && msg.sender != FounderAddress1 && msg.sender != FounderAddress2 && msg.sender != FounderAddress3 && msg.sender != FounderAddress4){}
```

Other

```
if(true){}
```

Comment: This may answer your question regarding executing IF excluding the gas of evaluating the conditional:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371346/10261711

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good rule of thumb: if there is logic or computations, it requires gas.

I tested the following contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract SimpleStore {
  function testGas1(uint a, uint b) {
    if (a == 1 && b == 2) {

    }
  }

  function testGas2(uint a, uint b) {
    if (true) {

    }
  }
}
```

Running the `testGas1` gives `"cumulativeGasUsed": 21918`

Running the `testGas2` gives `"cumulativeGasUsed": 21876`

You can do the same tests here: https://ethfiddle.com/AmIZSh7AnY